# Prevent instantiating items android instantiateItem

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter

Have current fun:

```
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val view = AuthorizationHeaderView(context = context)
    updateViewContent(view, data[position])
    timeUpdateListeners.add(view as TimeUpdateListener)
    container.addView(view, 0)
    return view
}
```

But right now I don't want to update the view multiple times. Since when calling the adapter I have a method: `instantiateItem` called several times.

I'm trying to rewrite as follows:

```
private val map = HashMap<String, View>()
```

And after want write smth like this:

```
if (map.containsKey(position)
    return map.get(position)
else
//make view and add to cotnainer
val view = makeView()
container.add(view)
map.put(position, view)
```

But there are some difficulties how to rewrite my current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getOrPut`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html) for this:

```
val view = map.getOrPut(position) { makeView().also { container.addView(it) } }
```

Or expanding out `also`, if you find that more readable:

```
val view = map.getOrPut(position) { 
    val tmp = makeView()
    container.addView(tmp)
    tmp
}
```

Above is assuming you only want to call `container.add` on newly created views, otherwise just

```
val view = map.getOrPut(position) { makeView() }
container.addView(view)
```

In the case of your specific code it's

```
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val view = map.getOrPut(position) {
        AuthorizationHeaderView(context = context)
    }
    updateViewContent(view, data[position])
    timeUpdateListeners.add(view as TimeUpdateListener)
    container.addView(view, 0)
    return view
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but the main idea was not to redraw the view several times, if it is already redrawn once. I did it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358796/6387618 .
Maybe you can improve this answer or revise your answer.

Comment: You simply need to replace your `val value = ...; val view = ...` with a single `getOrPut` call. I wrote it out just in case.

Comment: interesting observation, my `destroyItem` also called multiple times, and if i want to add `map.remove(position)` in this method, then I still have the view redrawn in `instantiateItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with next solution:

```
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val value: View? = map[position]
    val view = if (value != null) value
    else {
        val view = AuthorizationHeaderView(context = context)
        map.put(position, view)
        view
    }
    updateViewContent(view, data[position])
    timeUpdateListeners.add(view as TimeUpdateListener)
    container.addView(view, 0)
    return view
}
```